# How to add Facebook Messenger to react website

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I develop a react website
I want to add fb messenger to react website. I have a fb official code which is in HTML, How to add it in react.. Please help. Thank you

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v8.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=setup_tool
        page_id="100522201771081">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-messenger-customer-chat
```

Then it can be imported as React component. pageId and appId are required props, so remember pass them into it:

```
    import MessengerCustomerChat from 'react-messenger-customer-chat';
    const App = () => (  
      <div>
        <MessengerCustomerChat
          pageId="<YOUR_PAGE_ID>"
          appId="<YOUR_APP_ID>"
        />
      </div>
    );

    <MessengerCustomerChat
      pageId="<YOUR_PAGE_ID>"
      appId="<YOUR_APP_ID>"
      htmlRef={window.location.pathname}
    />
```

check please git github https://github.com/Yoctol/react-messenger-customer-chat

Comment: I try it. But nowadays Fb remove appID. :-(

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Comment: Did you guys found a solutions, seems like app id is not working?

Comment: Yes this package require an app id is there any other solution?